# lxml can not parse html fragment contains certain unicode character

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

lxml can not parse any html content that contains the character .

The python code below can not find the html element by xpath. Further more the result of `etree.tostring(root)` contails many extra whitespaces.

code:

```py
from lxml import html, etree

text = """<div id="content">
  
</div>
"""
root  = html.document_fromstring(text)

print(etree.tostring(root))
content = root.xpath("//div[@id='content']")
print(content)
```

Output:

```
b'<html><body><p>d   i   v       i   d   =   "   c   o   n   t   e   n   t   "   &gt;   \n           1\x14/p></body></html>'
[]
```

Update:
I believe this is due to a lxml bug. It has been fixed in lxml 4.4.3. However after checking lxml's changelog & commit history between 4.4.2-4.4.3, I still don't know the root cause.

Comment: What is exactly the **x** you are using. I have posted an answer but I dont know what should be `x`

Comment: @balderman https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d431/index.htm

Comment: answer was updated accordingally.

Comment: The spacing looks odd.  Are you retrieving the content from a UTF-16-encoded file or bytestring?

Comment: @snakecharmerbc From a UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: I can't reproduce on 4.4.2 but I get something similar to your output by removing the leading `<` from the opening div tag.   I suspect the original input was corrupted in some way.

Answer (score 0):

ElementTree based working solution below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.entity["#119857"] = 'x'
html = '''<html><body><p><div id='content'>&#119857;</div></p></body></html>'''
root = ET.fromstring(html)
content = root.find('.//div[@id="content"]')
print(content.text)
```

output

**x**